# Why does an icon change in the dash, after starting a program?

Tags: icons, sqldeveloper

sorry for re opening this but I'm not being able to make this work.
I tried creating the following file:
`/usr/share/applications/SQLDev.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment[en_US]=SQLDev42
Comment=SQLDev42
Exec=/home/user1/bin/sqldeveloper
GenericName[en_US]=SQLDev42
GenericName=SQLDev42
Icon=/home/user1/progs/sqldeveloper/sql.png
MimeType=
Name[en_US]=SQLDev42
Name=SQLDev42
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
```

The icon appears on my desktop and in the dash.  But as soon as the programs starts, the icon changes to '?' in the dash.  What can I do to prevent this change?

sqldeveloper is a symb link

```
user1@host1:~$ cat /home/user1/bin/sqldeveloper
export JAVA_HOME="/home/user1/progs/jdk1.8.0_102"
unset -v GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
cd /home/user1/progs/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin
./sqldeveloper "$@"

sudo update-desktop-database
```

If I check the WM_Class

```
user1@host1:~$ xprop WM_CLASS
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", ""
```

Is it because I'm using oracle jdk?

Comment: What is you question, exactly?  I cannot understand what you cannot make work (creation of an icon?).

Comment: No, after the program starts i keep getting '?' icon on dash instead of the icon that I have selected  in the .desktop file.

Comment: Does the correct icon appear on the desktop?

Comment: Yes, and even in the dash when the program is not running, after the program starts It changes from sql.png to '?'

Comment: OK, I do not have the answer but I edited your question to make it clearer (I hope), so that other people can answer it without having first to try and understand what you meant.  I let you judge if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Please add/change: The icon appears on my desktop and in the dash (when it is locked in the launcher). But as soon as the programs starts, the icon changes to '?' in the dash (when its not locked and launched from the desktop), if locked the icon remains as not running and launches a new icon '?' which is the sql developer window. What can I do to prevent this change? Sorry for the trouble I'm giving. https://postimg.org/image/4kz2c4h7f/

Comment: Anyone??? any help? this is annoying :(